# Extracting volume_id from a ec2 creation register

Tags: json, ansible

I need to extract the EBS volume ids from the register return from an EC2 creation call.  I've already got it down to a chuck which holds the data I want, but the last step eludes me.

I've tried to do it with:

```
- set_fact:
        volume_id_list: "{{ devices | json_query('[*].volume_id') }}"
    - debug: var=volume_id_list
```

And it returns an empty string.

```
    "devices": {
        "/dev/sdf": {
            "delete_on_termination": true, 
            "status": "attached", 
            "volume_id": "vol-0b2c92cdcblah"
        }, 
        "/dev/xvda": {
            "delete_on_termination": true, 
            "status": "attached", 
            "volume_id": "vol-086a722c4blah"
        }
    }
```

What I wanted to see was something like:

"vol-0b2c92cdcblah"
"vol-086a722c4blah"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) expression in `json_query` does not match anything in your data-structure. So the empty string is a totally correct result :)

Now, to get what your want from your current data-structure, you need to change your query: `json_query('*.volume_id')`

Comment: Tried that - still an empty list.

Comment: My bad!  Thank you - that works.  Thanks also for the pointer to jmespath documentation.  Very informative.

Comment: @cassini232 consider accepting the solution if this worked for you. This will let people know there is a correct response to your answer when they search.